# connection to database timing out in less than 30 seconds despite 300 second timeout in conn string

Tags: .net, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I am opening a connection to a sql azure serverless database.
This database pauses if unused for 1 hour.

I connect to this database via an azure function. The conn.open(); line times out after 10 seconds despite the connection string having timeout set to 300 seconds.
The database is also not unpausing on this connection attempt.

I had assumed that when a connection is made it will restart, and this may take a few minutes but the code seems to be ignoring the connection string timeout value.

Is there somewhere else i should set this timeout?

Conn String:

```
Server=tcp:myDBServer.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=sample-Db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_user};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=300;
```

Answer (score 0):

More than **30 minutes** idle connections can be closed by Azure SQL Database.

If you're connected from **SSMS** or any **other applications** to the Azure SQL DB for longer than **30** minutes without any active request, your **session will timeout**.

The default **`idleTimeout`** parameter before closing an unused connection is **`300000`** ms which would be enough for Azure SQL Connections.

Please check the workarounds given in this thread:

[How can I avoid a SqlClient timeout error during execution of a C# Azure Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610670/how-can-i-avoid-a-sqlclient-timeout-error-during-execution-of-a-c-sharp-azure-fu)

Answer (score 0):

The Connection Timeout in the ConnectionString only controls the timeout for the connection. If you need to increase the wait time on your Commands, use the `CommandTimeout` property of `SqlCommand`.